# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in httpclient.defaultrequestheaders.accept.add android xamarin

Tags: xamarin

```
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://example.Com/Service1.svc/Findemployee?uid=" + Username.ToString());
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                RootObject loginuserdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
                Strpassword = loginuserdata.FindemployeeResult;
            }


        }
```

error throw after update xamarin.forms at the line is                 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

Answer (score 0):

**Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.**

For mode details you can check [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

#### Solution

Create file **res/xml/network_security_config.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://example.Com/Service1.svc/Findemployee</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201083/discussion-on-answer-by-lucas-zhang-msft-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instan).