# Websocket in Webview Xamarin Forms not working

Tags: android, angular, xamarin, websocket

I have an angular web application. Now I want to open in Webview Xamarin Forms. The problem is that the WebSocket cannot connecting. 
If I open through the browser, then everything works without problems. 
I read somewhere that you need to allow android to use the locale storage.
But Xamarin does it default. But I still made my CustomWebview.

Thanks in advance!

```
            var settings = Control.Settings;
            settings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
            settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);

            settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            settings.BlockNetworkImage = false;
```

"WebSocket connection to 'ws://..' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED"

Comment: Update[0]: works on the Android Emulator without problems :)

Comment: Update[1]: Works on the Anroid 8 and below

Comment: Add the line <application android:label="xxx.Android" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> in Android project ->Manifest.xml .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT that already done

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58427568/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-httpclient-defaultreques/58428423#58428423